# video events run when they are set up - which I don't intend

Tags: html5-video

I have a video tag with events.
For example, I have code such as:
     myPlayer = document.getElementById("player");

```
      myPlayer.onended=reachedEnd();
       myPlayer.onpause = pauseEvent();
         myPlayer.onplay = resumePlayer();
```

The problem is, that the event functions run immediately, I doubt they run when they are supposed to, but they certainly run when they are defined.
what am I doing wrong? (I did do an alert of 'myPlayer', and it is a video object, so that part is correct).

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses next to the function names are causing the functions to run immediately. Instead, you want to refer to the functions like variables, passing references to them to the events. Instead, 'onended' etc. get set to the values returned by those functions, which is presumably `undefined`, so nothing happens when those events finally do occur.

Just get rid of the parentheses and you should be fine.